# Quando implementar funções no cabeçalho?

Tags: c, c++, arquivo-header

Costumo dividir o programa em módulos pequenos, cada um com seu próprio cabeçalho e implementação. Em geral, o nível de abstração utilizado permite que a implementação seja completamente alterada sem quebrar o restante do código que depende do módulo.

Em alguns benchmarks que rodei utilizando o callgrind, implementar as funções de um módulo bastante utilizado também no cabeçalho produziu ganhos consideráveis em performance. Nestes casos fiz o seguinte:

**modulo.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h> //cabecalhos necessários

#ifndef MODULO_IMPLEMENTACAO
inline int funcao1(int x, int y)
{
    //código
}

inline int funcao2(int x, int y, double z)
{
    //código
}
#endif
```

**modulo.c**

```
#define MODULO_IMPLEMENTACAO
#include "modulo.h"

extern inline int funcao1(int x, int y)
{
    //código
}

extern inline int funcao2(int x, int y, double z)
{
    //código
}
```

Se entendo corretamente, os problemas desta abordagem são o fato de ter de recompilar todos os arquivos que dependem do módulo em questão caso a implementação mude, o fato de demorar mais para compilar, e a criação de funções que antes não existiriam - as que eram declaradas `static` e implementads inline pelo compilador.

Há alguma outra desvantagem nesta prática? Quando implementar as funções no cabeçalho?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao incluir funções em cabeçalhos você deve marcar elas com o `inline`, e não é necessário reimplementar-las no source. Apenas uma vez basta.

**Vantagens:**

- Velocidade: O compilador poderá realizar otimizações muito melhores de posse do código de cada função ao compilar o código do cliente. Isso é especialmente verdade para funções pequenas de uma ou duas linhas. Para funções grandes ou que sejam pouco usadas, essa diferença é pouco significante.

**Desvantagens:**

- Tempo de compilação: O compilador terá mais código para analizar ao compilar cada arquivo. Em um projeto grande isso pode se traduzir em alguns segundos ou minutos. Se você já usou o *boost*, sentiu isso na pele.
- Tamanho do executável: Se sua implementação for posta em uma biblioteca compartilhada, ela pesará uma vez só no disco e na memoria. Imagine se a *libc* fosse implementada toda em cabeçalhos. Todo o executável teria uma cópia das funções e quando fosse aberto, guardaria na memoria código que poderia ter sido compartilhado entre outros processos.
- Recompilar: Ao alterar uma implementação, todo o codigo que a use precisará ser recompilado. Mais tempo gasto, mais trabalho realizado.
- Compactibilidade binária: Se a função posta em uma biblioteca compartilhada for modificada de forma que sua declaração no cabeçalho não mude, você poderá trocar o .dll/.so/.dylib pelo mais novo no programa que o use sem precisar recompilar coisa alguma. Será uma atualização transparente.

**Conclusão:**

Se é uma função crítica, pequena e que seja muito utilizada, pode valer a pena. Caso contrário, vale pensar se é realmente necessário a definir no cabeçalho.

No caso do C++, isso é na maioria dos casos inevitável com funções e classes templates. Essas precisam estar definidas em cabeçalhos para que sejam especializadas para outros tipos a cada uso.

Comment: Eu incluiria apenas o cabeçalho em `main.c`. `modulo.c` é um arquivo contendo as funções para o caso de o compilador decidir não implementar inline, http://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/2264920 (C99)

Comment: @Douglas, não é necessário. O compilador sempre incluirá as definições do header em todos os arquivos que o incluirem (as duplicatas e não usadas são removidas pelo linker mais tarde). No seu caso nem mesmo precisa ter o `modulo.c`.

Comment: mas e quanto à definição fornecida naquele link, está incorreta ou não entendi corretamente? E se o compilador decidir chamar uma função externa ao invés de implementar inline? "inline": no externally visible function is emitted, but one might be called and so must exist.

Comment: Outro ponto que pode ser levantado é que apenas precisam estar declaradas em arquivos .h funções que se deseja reutilizar em outros módulos. Se a função é "privada" daquele módulo ela pode ficar apenas no arquivo .c/.cpp e ser declarada como `inline` caso seja apropriado.

Comment: A verdadeira função do `inline` é suprimir erros de definição função duplicada na etapa de linker e assim permitir escrever ela em cabeçalhos. O compilador é completamente livre para decidir se aplicará a otimização ou não a qualquer função que encontre.

Answer (score 3):

Quando implementar o inline em um header, busque colocar o código diretamente no header, sem implementar no fonte:

```
inline int soma(int a, int b) {
 return a + b;
}
// Sem inline só declaração, conforme padrão
void DoXYZ();
```

**Nota sobre o inline**: Só use quando for um código bastante simples, que não passe de umas 10 linhas.. pois de qualquer forma, o compilador irá desmarcar o seu inline caso você tenha se excedido.. assim como marca como inline funções as quais você esqueceu de colocar a keyword 'inline'.

Nos casos em que você tem certeza de que deve ser inline, existe a diretiva `__forceinline`, e nesse caso o compilador respeita a vontade do programador.
Uma observação sobre o force inline, é que cada compilador pode especifica-lo de uma forma diferente, portanto é bom usar um macro para substituo-lo para cada compilador específico.

O que a diretiva inline deve fazer (ajuda a saber como e quando usar):

Quando se declara uma função em C ou C++, o compilador vai transformar no seguinte pseudo-assembly:

```
PUSH VAR1; // jogar valores do registro pra pilha
PUSH VAR2;
CALL SOMA; // executa função com os valores na pilha
{ pula para o código de máquina da FN1 .. }
POP VAR2; // retira os valores da pilha de volta aos registradores
POP VAR1;
```

Com o inline o código da função é exposto "puro" no binário executável:

```
JUMP SOMA
SOMA: 
 MOV {..}
 ADD {..}
```

A eficiência ganha nesse caso, é a economia das operações de push e pop da pilha/stack e da instrução CALL que é mais cara do que uma instrução JUMP

Pode deixar o código mais eficiente? Pode, mas desde que usado da maneira correta, caso contrário pode deixar o programa mais lento e com bugs se usado com exagero.. O melhor mesmo é nem usar o 'force inline' e deixar que o compilador tomes as decisões sozinho de forma automática.

Os compiladores atuais são extremamente sofisticados. Portanto use com cuidado e sem exageros.

Comment: Caso a função receba inline não haverá JUMP, o código será imbutido diretamente no caller. No GCC/Clang, o atributo para forçar o inline é `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

Comment: Tem razão Guilherme. O binário resultante será simplesmente copiado quantas vezes for usado diretamente no conjunto de código em que está sendo usado. Continua a reutilização no fonte C, mas no resultado, é sempre recopiado pelas vezes em que o método inline é utilizado. Economiza aquela instrução JUMP também. Obrigado pela correçao.

Answer (score 0):

A principio, notei um erro...

**MODULO.H**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef MODULO_IMPLEMENTACAO
#define MODULO_IMPLEMENTACAO
... (restante)
```

**MODULO.C**

```
#include "modulo.h"
... (restante)
```

O ideal é que caso não tenha sido definido o modulo, ele então defina. Isso deve estar dentro do modulo.h e não do modulo.c.
No modulo.c basta o "#include modulo.h"

A ideia de cabeçalhos é (como vc já citou) não ter que recompilar tudo que você já tinha feito previamente. Imagine que no projeto principal (Main.c) você usa uma classe que já está em funcionando perfeitamente, e você só esteja fazendo alterações no Main.c, caso vc recompile, a classe será compilada novamente e não há necessidade disto.
Pensando em um projeto pequeno com certeza não vai demorar muito, mas imagine algo mais extenso? Que tal apelarmos para o Linux que foi programado em C++? Imagine quanto tempo levaria se cada alteração miníma feita no Main.c recompilasse TODO o projeto (Os cabeçalhos da rede, do visual, do gerenciamento de arquivos), enfim, levaria muito tempo.

Outra grande vantagem é a organização de código. Pra você não cometer o erro de alterar o que já funcionava perfeitamente e também saber aonde encontrar determinada parte do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Um dos problemas de fazer isso é que o compilador vai recompilar essa função várias vezes, uma para cada `.c` ou `.cpp` que incluir esse header, e o compilador também vai entender que essa função é uma função distinta de cada `.c` ou `.cpp` apesar de ter o mesmo nome e fazer a mesma coisa para todos eles.

Isso aumentará o tamanho do binário, pois trará várias redundâncias de código, e aumentará também o tempo de compilação. É por isso que normalmente a implementação dessas funções é feita num `.cpp` e os headers trazem somente a declaração.

Além disso, você pode observer que ao compilar o programa, cada `.cpp` gera um `.obj` distinto que será em seguida processado pelo linker para gerar o binário executável final. Quando você recompila após fazer uma alteração no programa, somente os arquivos afetados são recompilados, para agilizar. Isso significa que você não quer alterar headers o tempo todo, pois todos os `.cpp` que estiverem utilizando-os vão precisar ser recompilados também. Evitando mexer nos headers você dribla esse problema e ganha tempo.